# Android Studio: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: BadUsername

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I simply do not know what the issue is. I read all API docs and looked at 1 available StackOverflow question to no avail. I did generate the client ID and stuff that match my package name and debug SHA1 code. My goal is to connect to a specific Google account regardless of user and the device. In a sense that account is a back-end database for me but functions as regular drive account. I do not want anything to do with AccountManager/Picker either. This seems to be such shady and obscure subject and I would greatly appreciate if anyone shed some light on it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new RetrieveTokenTask().execute();

}

private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String token = "";
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), "288683421512-blablablamyuserblabla.apps.googleusercontent.com", "oauth2:drive");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return token;
    }


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Note that `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` needs to be used with an existing account on the device. For example, for this API, [https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), you should pass in a Google account's name that is existing on the device as the 2nd parameter.